# Azure Maps Disabled Drag on Touch

Tags: uiscrollview, touch, azure-maps

On azure maps I have the examples from : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/map-events

Drag is disabled correctly but the page doesn't scroll at all when touch on map Anyone has experienced this at all or have used azure maps before.
**Using Android Chrome Browser.**

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information, it isn't clear what you are doing. Are you setting the dragPanInteraction map option to false to disable panning? If so, that is only for the mouse events, not touch. To disable touch you set touchInteraction map option to false.

Comment: @ rbrundritt  I am looking to do the same thing as google maps does on mobile `use two fingers to interact with the map` but when touchInteraction is disabled I can't scroll the page, only if touch is outside the the map div is scrollable.

Comment: @rbrundritt besides my last comment I've set touchInteraction and interaction to ` false`  yet I am still interacting with the map it seem it doesn't work!

Comment: I'll take a look at the touchInteraction issue. Two finger panning is not a part of the Azure Maps experience at this time.

Comment: @rbrundritt How are supposed to handle touch on mobile as if you touch the map it does not allow to scroll the page especially android phones. On touch `e.map.map.dragPan. _state` = 'disabled' then it's fine does not drag but does not allow to scroll the page? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED!

The bellow is my sample on touch and 2 fingers interact with the map disable drag on 1 touch and able scroll. this purpose only for mobile so i am not checking for mobile device 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Map Events - Azure Maps Web Control Samples</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="This sample will highlight the name of the events that are firing as you interact with the map." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="map, gis, API, SDK, events, click, mouse, touch, context menu, wheel, zoomed, panned, dragged, pitched, moved" />
    <meta name="author" content="Microsoft Azure Maps" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Add references to the Azure Maps Map control JavaScript and CSS files. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/css/atlas.min.css?api-version=2" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/js/atlas.min.js?api-version=2"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var map, drag;
        function GetMap() {
            //Initialize a map instance.
            map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
                //Add your Azure Maps subscription key to the map SDK. Get an Azure Maps key at https://azure.com/maps
                authOptions: {
                    authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                    subscriptionKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
                }
            });
            //Wait until the map resources are ready.
            map.events.add('ready', function () {
                map.setUserInteraction({dragPanInteraction: false, dblClickZoomInteraction: false});
                map.events.add('touchstart', function (e) {
                    if(e.originalEvent.touches.length === 2) {
                        $('#message').removeClass('messageOverlay');
                        map.setUserInteraction({ dragPanInteraction: true, dblClickZoomInteraction: true });
                    }else {
                        $('#message').addClass('messageOverlay');
                        map.setUserInteraction({dblClickZoomInteraction: false});
                    }
                });
                map.events.add('dragstart', function (e) {
                    if(e.originalEvent.touches.length === 1) {
                        $('#message').addClass('messageOverlay');
                        map.setUserInteraction({dragPanInteraction: false, dblClickZoomInteraction: false});
                    }else {
                        map.setUserInteraction({dragPanInteraction: true, dblClickZoomInteraction: true});
                        $('#message').removeClass('messageOverlay');
                    }
                });
                map.events.add('dragend', function (e) {
                  map.setUserInteraction({dragPanInteraction: false, dblClickZoomInteraction: false});
                });
                map.events.add('touchend', function (e) {
                    $('#message').removeClass('messageOverlay');
                })
            });
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        #message {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 0.5s;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block !important;
            font-size: 23px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        .messageOverlay {
            transition: all 0.5s;
            background-color: hsla(1, 1%, 1%, 0.5);
            z-index: 1 !important;
            opacity: 1 !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="GetMap()">
<div style="position: relative">
    <div class="" id="message">Use two finger to use the map</div>
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:100%;min-width:350px;height:400px;"></div>
</div>
<p>Add Lots of new line for scroll</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
I am the end
</body>
</html>
```

That's it.
This is now fully working for me as it should with no glitches

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured out how to achieve two finger panning of the map and single finger panning of the page when the touch is on top of the map. Here is a code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

    <!-- Add references to the Azure Maps Map control JavaScript and CSS files. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/css/atlas.min.css?api-version=2" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/js/atlas.min.js?api-version=2"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var map, datasource;

        function GetMap() {
            //Initialize a map instance.
            map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
                //Add your Azure Maps subscription key to the map SDK. Get an Azure Maps key at https://azure.com/maps
                authOptions: {
                    authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                    subscriptionKey: '<Your Azure Maps Key>'
                }
            });

            //Restrict the map to two finger panning only.
            RestrictMapToTwoFingerPan(map);
        }

        function RestrictMapToTwoFingerPan(map) {
            var pointerCount = 0;

            //Monitor the drag start event.
            map.events.add('dragstart', function (e) {
                //Determine if the drag event is due to touch.
                if (e.originalEvent && pointerCount === 1) {
                    //If there is only one touch point, disable drag panning by disablling, then re-enabling to cancel the current pan request.
                    //Disable then re-enable the drag panning. This will cancel the single touch drag functionality.
                    map.setUserInteraction({ dragPanInteraction: false });
                    map.setUserInteraction({ dragPanInteraction: true });
                }
            });

            //Add touch events to the map container and monitor the movement and move the page accordingly when there is a single touch.

            var pageX = 0;
            var pageY = 0;
            var scale = 1;

            var mapDiv = map.getMapContainer();  

            var touchStartHandler = function (e) {
                var px, py;
                if (window.PointerEvent) {
                    if (e.pointerType !== 'touch') {
                        return;
                    }

                    pointerCount++;
                    px = e.pageX;
                    py = e.pageY;
                } else {
                    pointerCount = e.touches.length;
                    px = e.touches[0].pageX;
                    py = e.touches[0].pageY;
                }

                if (pointerCount === 2) {
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }

                pageX = px;
                pageY = py;
            };

            var touchMoveHandler = function (e) {
                var px, py;
                if (window.PointerEvent) {
                    if (e.pointerType !== 'touch') {
                        return;
                    }

                    px = pageX - e.screenX;
                    py = pageY - e.screenY;
                } else {
                    pointerCount = e.touches.length;
                    px = pageX - e.touches[0].screenX;
                    py = pageY - e.touches[0].screenY;
                }

                if (pointerCount === 2) {
                    return;
                }

                if (scale === e.scale) {
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

                scale = e.scale;

                window.scrollTo(px, py);
            };

            //Add support for Pointer Events and fallback onto touch events. Edge only supports pointer events, and Safari only supports touch events. Chrome supports both.
            if (window.PointerEvent) {
                mapDiv.addEventListener('pointerdown', touchStartHandler, false);

                mapDiv.addEventListener('pointerup', (e) => {
                    if (e.pointerType === 'touch') {
                        pointerCount--;
                    }
                }, false);

                mapDiv.addEventListener('pointermove', touchMoveHandler, false);
            } else {
                mapDiv.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStartHandler, false);
                mapDiv.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMoveHandler, false);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="GetMap()">
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:600px;"></div>

    <br /><br />Adding several new lines so that the sample can be scrolled.<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

You can try this out here: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html?sample=Limit%20Map%20to%20Two%20Finger%20Panning

Comment: It's a bit buggy it jumps right back when trying to scroll also when you interact with the map two fingers then try to scroll it would be stuck for a couple of second then keeps jumping again. it seem a little over kill. what I was looking for is `setUserInteraction` method which helped and it seem to do the job, I will post my answer soon so you can have look. there only one issue, after two finger interaction it needs 2 touches to be able to scroll nicely but I can leave with that. Thanks